# Import page in Mediawiki

Tags: javascript, import, mediawiki

I create a script ( js ) to import a page in my mediawiki.
I have a "incorrect token". What's wrong ?

```
var xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp");
xmlHttp2.open("POST", url, false);
xmlHttp2.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHttp2.send("action=query&prop=info&intoken=import&titles=Test2"); 
var result2 = xmlHttp2.responseText;
var resultTokenImport = extractTokenImport(result2); 
//return me 'dsa7u6ds6u7asd76das67sad+\' ( more or less :D )

xmlHttp2.open("POST", url, false);
xmlHttp2.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHttp2.send("action=import&format=xml&xml="+dump+"&token="+resultTokenImport);
```

---

Well, the problem is that 'import' need 'another' type of Token.

now, my problem is:

```
xmlHttp2.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

give me an error "nofile"

and for this code :

```
xmlHttp2.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
```

it send me a:

Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in **Unknown** on line 0

Answer (score 1):

If it says "no file" it is expecting a file in a POST body. You can easily POST using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

To quote from /api.php

```
    xml      - Uploaded XML file
               Must be posted as a file upload using multipart/form-data
```

## Example

Here is what is working for me. For simplicity, the following code is reading from a textarea and makes use of MediaWiki's JavaScript includes:

```
var apiUrl = mw.util.wikiScript( 'api' );
var onreadystatechange = function() {
  if ( 4 !== this.readyState ) return;
  if ( 200 === this.status ) {
    console.log( this.response );
  }
};

function continueWithToken ( token ) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // First argument is an array!
    var bXml = new Blob( [$( 'textarea' ).val()], {
            type: 'text/xml'
        } );
    fd.append( 'format', 'json' );
    fd.append( 'action', 'import' );
    // Third parameter is not required but
    // You're likely on the safe side using it
    fd.append( 'xml', bXml, 'file.xml' );
    fd.append( 'token', token );

    xhr.onreadystatechange = onreadystatechange;
    xhr.open( 'POST', apiUrl );
    xhr.send( fd );
}

$.get( apiUrl, {
    format: 'json',
    type: 'import',
    action: 'tokens'
} ).done( function(r) {
    var token = r.tokens.importtoken;
    continueWithToken( token );
} );
```

This is just a minimal implementation. Do not forget error-handling. If you have the exports as files for upload and want to make it working in older browsers not sufficiently supporting Blobs and FormData, just build a form! The form's target could be an iframe so you can read the response from it without exposing the blank API result page to your users.

## Expected response

```
{"import":[{"ns":0,"title":"Main Page2","revisions":1}]}
```

## Complete request

The request that is composed by the client and sent to the server for reference. Note the file's in a POST body.

```
POST http://localhost/api.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: <ua string>
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost/index.php?title=Special:Export&action=submit
Content-Length: 3231
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------768648126486
Cookie: <redacted>; mwdbUserID=1; mwdbUserName=Rillke
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

-----------------------768648126486
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="format"

json
-----------------------768648126486
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action"

import
-----------------------768648126486
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="xml"; filename="file.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml

<mediawiki ...schemas... version="0.8" xml:lang="en">
  <siteinfo>
    <sitename>Sample Wiki</sitename>
    <!-- .... -->
</mediawiki>
-----------------------768648126486
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="token"

XX39e9fd22a9de7675c71eadcfd2XXXX+\
-----------------------768648126486--
```

As for the "Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data" error, this is because you send it url-encoded but claim it would be [multipart/form-data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4). MediaWiki is looking for a boundary in the header but cannot find it.